# Firebase rules only if user authenticated

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is it possible only read,write if user authenticated in firebase?

[image: example image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403747/firebase-permission-denied). I also recommend checking out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408642/what-do-these-default-security-rules-for-the-firebase-realtime-database-mean

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) when you need to refer to code in a question, please paste it in as text instead of using a screenshot - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course.
First, select Firestore Database in the Firebase console, then select the Rules tab above.

and delete all the codes, paste the following codes there. Then publish it.

Here Cloud Firestore example:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write : if request.auth!=null;
  }
 }
}
```

You can also use this code for Firebase Storage.
Here for more info: [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure)